# What is the type of $event in angular-12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am calling the following function from the HTML template on click of the button

```
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onAddItems($event)">Add</button>
```

And the declaration of the function is bellow

```
onAddItems(event:?){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

What should I write in the place of the **'?' symbol**. What is the data type of $event?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Easy way to find out: put a breakpoint in your method and you'll see the type. It might depends on how the user interacted though.

Answer (score 3):

It's MouseEvent

```
onAddItems(event:MouseEvent){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

The `MouseEvent` interface represents events that occur due to the user interacting with a pointing device (such as a mouse). Common events using this interface include click, dblclick, mouseup, mousedown.

For more details visit this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)

Comment: Even if the user clicks using keyboard? Like using space key.